# Can I be married to multiple people?

Tags: international, marriage

One person is from the US, one UK, one somewhere else

All of the countries above allow dual citizenship if that's relevant. I won't be a US or UK citizen.

I can marry them in the country where they're from

I'm going to split my time in 3 countries equally but they'll live full time in their country. I won't lie to them.

Is this ok?

Answer (score 4):

No, and certainly not for the reason implied (essentially a one spouse per jurisdiction in which one has citizenship rule which doesn't exist anywhere).

At least under the law of every U.S. jurisdiction, you cannot be married to more than one person at the same time (anywhere in the world), and it is a crime to do so.

Several dozen countries in the world recognize polygamy as legal (mostly in predominantly Muslim countries, not all of which allow polygamy, and in Africa where pre-Christian custom permits it), of course, and this does not violate the laws of those jurisdictions.

The U.K. does not generally permit polygamy, but gives some recognition to and does not criminalize, polygamous marriages entered into in a place where it is lawful. But the concept proposed in the question would still not be legal under U.K. law.

UPDATE: A [California court ruling concurs](https://reason.com/volokh/2022/06/09/california-court-rejects-lebanese-bigamous-marriage/) with this analysis.

Comment: How does that concern me? I'm not a resident of those jurisdictions. I'm not a citizen of those jurisdictions. My spouses won't be breaking any laws.

Comment: @user44600 At Law.SE we provide answers concerning what the law is, not whether the law is a good idea or not. And, your spouse would be violating laws by doing so if your spouse were aware of your multiple marriages.

Comment: As an added example. If you want to get legally married in Germany, you need to prove that you are not already married. Especially if one side is not a German citizen this can be quite onerous and requires official documention from the country of citizenship.

Answer (score 1):

It is irrelevant to the question where a person is "from" or where their citizenship is, what matters is who is married to multiple people, and where that person wants said marriages to be legally recognized. If you reside in the US and want the marriages to be recognized, you are out of luck. If you are in Saudi Arabia, you might be in luck – w.r.t. Saudi law.

To be married in Saudi Arabia, you and the/a spouse must be Muslim, must have a residence permit, the female must have written consent from her guardian ~ sponsor (father, brother, uncle). This page spells out the procedure for two foreigners with *Iqama* to get married. There is a certain amount of paperwork, involving the marriage contract and getting a marriage official assigned.